# Clark evans aggregation index in Python

Tags: python, statistics, cluster-analysis, spatial

The [Clark-Evans index](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spatstat.core/versions/2.3-0/topics/clarkevans.test) is one of the most basic statistics to measure point aggregation in spatial analysis. However, I can't find any implementation in Python. So I adapted the R code from the hyperlink above. I want to ask if the **statistic and p-value are correct with such irregular study areas**:

### Function

```
import numpy as np
import os, math
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
from statistics import NormalDist

def clarkEvans (X, Y, roi):
    """ Clark evans index takes point x,y coordinates and a polygon for cell shape (roi) and outputs Clark-Evans index:
    R ~1 suggests spatial randomness, while R<<1 suggests clustering and R>>1 suggests ordering"""

    # Import cell boundries from roi file 
    pgon = Polygon(roi)

    # Calculate intensity from points/area
    areaW = pgon.area
    npts = len(X)
    intensity = npts/areaW
    if npts <2:
        return(np.nan)

    tmp_df = list(zip(X, Y))

    # Get nearest neighbours for each observation
    kdt = KDTree(tmp_df, leaf_size=30, metric='euclidean')  # This is very good for large datasets, but maybe bad for small ones?
    dists, ids = kdt.query(tmp_df, k=2)
    dists = [x[1] for x in dists] 

    # Clark-Evans Index (mean NN distances/mean NN distances under poisson)
    Dobs = np.mean(dists)
    Dpoison = 1/(2 * math.sqrt(intensity))
    Rnaive = Dobs/Dpoison

    # Calculate p-value under normal distribution
    SE = math.sqrt(((4 - math.pi) * areaW)/(4 * math.pi))/npts
    Z  = (Dobs - Dpoison)/SE

    # Diff between observed and expected NN distances should have Normal Distribution according to Central Limit Theorem (CLT)
    p_val = NormalDist().pdf(Z)  # p_val for clustering 

    # Return the ClarkEvans Index and p-value
    return(round(Rnaive,3), round(p_val, 3))
```

### Output

In the image is my Clark-Evans Index being applied to and plotted with two different datasets. The index is similar for both patterns, one of which seems more obviously clustered. The p-values seem switched, I would think the second plot would have a significant p-val, being the clustered one.

[image: Application of CE index]

#### Input data

```
# The xy coordinates of observations plus the point vertices of the study area (roi)
x1 = [123, 105, 71, 109, 96, 49, 86, 80, 120, 98, 59, 100, 118, 69, 84, 21, 95, 77, 158, 118, 87, 77, 87, 77, 82, 106, 120, 125, 61, 24, 53, 106, 52, 103, 89, 99, 111, 58, 97, 83, 51, 45, 64, 112, 114, 73, 55, 111, 110, 102, 116, 107, 84, 97, 118, 96, 116, 45, 102, 145, 126, 50, 103, 98, 20, 79, 113, 99, 90, 143, 36, 120, 106, 91, 95, 15, 122, 69, 28, 71, 66, 119, 78, 75, 113, 44, 85, 60, 88, 68, 116, 40, 59, 105, 65, 94, 79, 95, 120, 67, 78, 59, 89, 84, 111, 78, 72, 156, 162, 134, 157, 120, 126, 86, 58, 137, 32, 91, 68, 119, 112, 70, 120, 62, 118, 114, 66, 55, 99, 72, 91, 109, 53, 94, 71, 145, 146, 106, 15, 83, 104, 61, 129, 51, 58, 59, 113, 107, 94, 94, 69, 118, 74, 124, 107, 99, 66, 115, 159, 71, 115, 122, 76, 68, 79, 107, 81, 104, 87, 106, 105, 112, 111, 79, 54, 108, 62, 115, 36, 74, 84, 75, 64, 92, 64, 82, 77, 56, 75, 69, 88, 105, 96, 61, 84, 106, 31, 53, 173, 102, 99, 124, 87, 70, 25, 19, 122, 101, 126, 60, 94, 78, 97, 64, 45, 92, 114, 87, 96, 160, 88, 66, 40, 124, 103, 60, 129, 120, 35, 95, 56, 76, 116, 65, 7, 103, 160, 63, 134, 101, 56, 50, 89, 92, 99, 89, 120, 47, 58, 47, 74, 124, 8, 93, 121, 53, 66, 63, 90, 114, 91, 71, 123, 55, 142, 97, 69, 141, 92, 76, 69, 74, 66, 90, 81, 96, 110, 61, 58, 62, 50, 125, 106, 115, 79, 94, 118, 117, 64, 99, 55, 53, 93, 57, 116, 61, 125, 10, 119, 74, 64, 77, 127, 115, 59, 53, 99, 81, 68, 101, 43, 122, 129, 109, 108, 84, 103, 59, 105, 76, 122, 101, 101, 108, 79, 75, 60, 111, 97, 104, 82, 67, 96, 70, 96, 104, 103, 66, 89, 114, 121, 119, 104, 93, 156, 108, 88, 98, 52, 112, 65, 99, 107, 90, 107, 115, 73, 106, 100, 120, 128, 66, 116, 69, 113, 69, 103, 62, 124, 110, 124, 72, 76, 115, 73, 84, 95, 100, 51, 61, 82, 97, 106, 68, 112, 69, 115, 67, 80, 72, 63, 123, 92, 101, 61, 69, 103, 112, 70, 59, 91, 90, 102, 111, 41, 101, 90, 33, 122, 161, 161]
y1 = [37, 51, 35, 67, 94, 114, 62, 24, 64, 92, 55, 11, 74, 38, 79, 77, 90, 77, 70, 70, 41, 46, 81, 83, 81, 65, 63, 43, 56, 95, 26, 8, 68, 82, 44, 78, 77, 72, 45, 68, 83, 99, 100, 58, 91, 89, 115, 34, 46, 68, 79, 71, 41, 43, 48, 83, 67, 69, 42, 55, 63, 69, 47, 67, 102, 72, 33, 77, 67, 1, 123, 59, 69, 47, 73, 79, 89, 48, 55, 97, 56, 92, 121, 70, 48, 47, 114, 62, 84, 78, 54, 55, 79, 76, 62, 63, 83, 71, 74, 83, 50, 67, 84, 81, 75, 59, 12, 77, 97, 6, 26, 55, 10, 74, 58, 59, 77, 76, 77, 68, 60, 50, 53, 89, 76, 87, 67, 86, 86, 73, 79, 74, 62, 54, 67, 58, 23, 76, 95, 63, 38, 76, 117, 18, 52, 46, 98, 62, 44, 36, 86, 52, 74, 51, 85, 100, 75, 73, 63, 38, 64, 91, 47, 70, 77, 88, 70, 88, 88, 39, 52, 45, 79, 56, 74, 60, 59, 69, 116, 44, 55, 48, 70, 83, 66, 87, 78, 73, 58, 76, 46, 50, 43, 81, 102, 45, 115, 88, 80, 34, 55, 55, 97, 103, 112, 122, 111, 97, 90, 81, 22, 36, 87, 86, 48, 39, 42, 83, 57, 16, 100, 89, 115, 75, 69, 86, 69, 69, 74, 39, 52, 23, 63, 49, 92, 96, 71, 105, 10, 75, 84, 80, 30, 30, 59, 52, 32, 119, 107, 74, 79, 101, 106, 99, 77, 66, 89, 83, 102, 94, 97, 78, 91, 93, 16, 11, 33, 16, 78, 50, 30, 26, 79, 34, 32, 86, 64, 40, 63, 51, 58, 52, 92, 98, 35, 36, 34, 47, 86, 88, 60, 80, 92, 96, 94, 94, 98, 111, 49, 54, 56, 36, 72, 94, 92, 102, 105, 32, 40, 30, 73, 59, 107, 39, 46, 40, 53, 57, 93, 92, 63, 59, 65, 68, 81, 69, 56, 53, 53, 85, 56, 55, 93, 45, 40, 68, 101, 93, 29, 44, 93, 93, 46, 67, 38, 34, 97, 93, 72, 90, 62, 68, 32, 31, 74, 71, 59, 38, 51, 95, 73, 82, 5, 53, 50, 34, 49, 43, 82, 77, 65, 88, 87, 89, 30, 38, 45, 36, 79, 89, 88, 100, 98, 45, 41, 20, 35, 51, 77, 64, 60, 63, 33, 44, 78, 82, 83, 70, 74, 78, 41, 61, 71, 40, 124, 82, 67, 121, 5, 65, 66]
roi1 = [[152.5078125, 3.7060546875], [158.8408203125, 12.455078125], [165.5126953125, 25.3154296875], [170.796875, 38.787109375], [171.013671875, 46.02734375], [172.6083984375, 53.0615234375], [172.6083984375, 63.9306640625], [174.419921875, 70.9169921875], [174.419921875, 85.41015625], [175.947265625, 92.4296875], [175.7998046875, 103.2626953125], [169.52734375, 116.3212890625], [166.9765625, 118.89453125], [159.7451171875, 119.2177734375], [152.7265625, 121.01953125], [138.2333984375, 121.029296875], [131.21875, 122.8408203125], [73.248046875, 122.8408203125], [66.2119140625, 124.5546875], [58.966796875, 124.65234375], [51.9990234375, 126.4638671875], [23.013671875, 126.4638671875], [19.42578125, 125.958984375], [16.5361328125, 123.7734375], [10.20703125, 115.0283203125], [0.5068359375, 95.57421875], [0.5537109375, 91.951171875], [9.0869140625, 80.318359375], [12.552734375, 73.9599609375], [18.884765625, 65.2119140625], [25.89453125, 56.994140625], [35.611328125, 41.7626953125], [42.345703125, 33.296875], [45.7568359375, 26.90625], [53.634765625, 14.7744140625], [58.1103515625, 9.078125], [64.916015625, 6.8984375], [86.654296875, 6.8984375], [93.6904296875, 5.291015625], [100.89453125, 4.57421875], [104.2763671875, 3.275390625], [122.3837890625, 3.025390625], [129.3935546875, 1.4638671875], [143.8857421875, 1.4638671875], [147.376953125, 0.4931640625]]
clarkEvans (x1, y1, roi1)

x2 = [94, 111, 79, 95, 86, 46, 30, 34, 53, 17, 44, 20, 42, 56, 23, 21, 50, 16, 50, 52, 47, 132, 44, 40, 43, 33, 29, 52, 24, 125, 86, 84]
y2 = [17, 71, 94, 88, 108, 132, 116, 115, 121, 132, 120, 121, 123, 116, 116, 139, 121, 124, 116, 140, 141, 33, 119, 118, 125, 130, 123, 122, 40, 23, 80, 107]
roi2 = [[129.4560546875, 3.6552734375], [132.3408203125, 5.84765625], [134.4638671875, 12.7744140625], [134.4638671875, 45.3828125], [132.65234375, 56.0302734375], [132.65234375, 66.8994140625], [131.4169921875, 70.3056640625], [130.7021484375, 77.5029296875], [129.029296875, 84.5419921875], [129.029296875, 88.1650390625], [127.2177734375, 95.1728515625], [127.16796875, 106.04296875], [125.40625, 113.0712890625], [125.40625, 116.6943359375], [123.896484375, 119.9873046875], [120.6533203125, 121.6025390625], [110.0654296875, 123.9130859375], [99.6181640625, 126.8427734375], [89.896484375, 131.7041015625], [83.8388671875, 135.638671875], [77.03515625, 138.134765625], [73.4228515625, 138.40625], [56.181640625, 143.8408203125], [45.568359375, 142.029296875], [31.076171875, 142.029296875], [27.4736328125, 141.6455078125], [20.626953125, 139.302734375], [15.5029296875, 134.1787109375], [11.0546875, 128.5234375], [4.537109375, 115.5849609375], [0.40625, 98.0078125], [0.513671875, 72.646484375], [4.927734375, 55.0859375], [11.4091796875, 42.123046875], [15.333984375, 36.0859375], [21.94921875, 27.4912109375], [34.7587890625, 14.6806640625], [43.416015625, 8.205078125], [57.9013671875, 7.970703125], [61.28125, 6.666015625], [71.9052734375, 4.541015625], [82.7705078125, 4.34765625], [89.7578125, 2.5361328125], [107.873046875, 2.5361328125], [114.8916015625, 1.015625], [122.126953125, 0.724609375]]
clarkEvans (x2, y2, roi2)
```

Using the original R function yields similar but not equal results:

```
clarkevans.test(X, alternative = "clustered")

 >R= 0.87719, p-value = 9.542e-07  # First dataset
 >R= 0.83365, p-value = 0.03591    # Second dataset
```

I'm not sure if the statistic and p-value calculation are valid since my study areas are irregularly shaped. The variable SE is calculated with pi, which seems like it is estimating a random distribution in a circular study area. Should I do Monte Carlo simulations instead? Is there a way of avoiding that?

Cheers!

Comment: I would suggest editing the question to make it more focused, on a single well-defined question that isn't a variation on "what do people think", and ideally provide a code snippet with embedded data (e.g. `arr = np.array([...])`).  Constructing simple test data may lead to new insights for yourself as well.

Comment: I think the p-value for the second dataset is larger because the sample is much smaller.  Note that the p-value depends on `npts` as well as the clustering pattern (see equation for `SE`).

Comment: Hey TMBailey, thanks for the comments. I added the raw data used to create the plots. And focused the question on p-value calculation in a context of an irregular study area.

Comment: It would help a lot if you add the necessary `import` statements to your input data code snippet so that it will actually run (when combined with `clarkEvans`).  That said, the first thing I would do would be to define a few datasets of equal size with about four points in each (e.g. x=+/-1 etc.) to eliminate the effect of `npts` on the p-value.  You could then examine clustering or edge effects or compare results with R with tightly controlled data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not worked with the Clark-Evans (CE) index before, but having read the information you linked to and studied your code, my interpretation is this:

- The index value for Dataset2 is less than the index value for Dataset1.  This correctly reflects the visual difference in clusteredness, that is, the smaller index value is associated with data that is more clustered.
- It is probably not meaningful to say that two CE index values are similar, other than special cases like observing that two CE index values are both smaller than 1 or both greater than 1, or if A < B < C then AB are more similar than AC.
- The p-value and the index value measure different things.  The index value measures degree of clusteredness (if less than 1) or regularity (if greater than 1).  The p-value (inversely) measures how certain it is that the data are more clustered than would be expected by chance, or more regular than would be expected by chance.  The p-value in particular is sensitive to the sample size as well as the distribution of points.
- The use of pi in calculating SE reflects the assumption of Euclidean distances between points (rather than, say, city block distances).  That is, the nearest neighbour of a point is the one at the smallest radial distance.  The use of pi in calculating SE does not make any assumptions about the shape of the region of interest.
- Particularly for small datasets (like Dataset2) you will want to track down information about the potential impact of boundary effects on the index value or the p-value.

More speculatively, I wonder if it would be useful to use a convex hull to help determine the region of interest rather than do this subjectively.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer and comments. I will explore different simulated cases as you suggested, to understand the effect of point number and edges. Cheers!